# Pass file to asp.net controller using angular

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i need upload file from

```
<input class="fromFileInput" id="VeryfyFromFileInput" type="file" fileread="fileContent" ng-click=uploadFile />
```

using angular

controller:

```
    $scope.fileInformation = [];

    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        $scope.fileModel = $('#VeryfyFromFileInput');
        recordsService.passFile($scope.fileModel.context);
    };
```

service:

```
        this.passFile = function (data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url + "/GetFile",
            data: data,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
```

To ASP.NET MVC controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void GetFile([FromBody] HttpRequestMessage file)
    {

    }
```

But i have always null, so which type of parameters i must use instead of 'HttpRequestMessage '? Or maybe problem in JS side?

Comment: Have you check whether or not `data` contains anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass bytedata over the wire as application/json. One solution is to use a Form Data object and make the ajax call as a multipart/formdata. Use the following Ajax call.

```
         $.ajax({
                url: 'api/controller/action',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formDataObject,
                success: function () {
                    alert('yay!');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('nay :c');
                }
            });
```

I used angular-ui file upload directive. I'm not sure if the way you're accessing it works, if it does then you can simply use the following syntax to add your file to FormData

```
var formDataObject = new FormData();
formDataObject.append('file', $scope.fileModel;
```

On the server use this snippet to access your data

```
 var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
 foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
 switch (stream.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name)
                {
                    case "\"file\"":
                        byte[] fileData = await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }

            }
```

For information on how to write a byte array as file to server follow: [Write File to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017980/save-file-from-byte-array-on-servermap-path)

Good luck!

Comment: Can you little bit more describe

Comment: about filesReadProvider. I don't want read content of file, i need just create the same file in my directory(on server)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please accept and upvote if it was helpful. Good luck!